# EKEventEditViewAction compiler error

Tags: swift

When I'm implementing the function below, I get a compiler error on the last line of this snippet that says `EKEventEditViewAction` is not convertible to `NSObject` which I don't really understand as they should be both `EKEventEditViewAction`s. Am I missing something?

```
func eventEditViewController(controller: EKEventEditViewController!, didCompleteWithAction action: EKEventEditViewAction) {

    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if (action == EKEventEditViewActionSaved) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare action with EKEventEditViewActionSaved you have to compare there value.

```
if (action.value == EKEventEditViewActionSaved.value) {

println("Event is to be Saved")

}
```